# What is the proper way of init of application ear under jboss

Tags: spring, jboss, initialization

i need right at the start of my ear that some code was executed to init application before it is used. So i wonder what is the proper way of doing this, possibly via some jboss configs, or via spring?

I' using spring3 and jboss4

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring, use a Spring way, then you won't be tied to JBoss if you ever move off it.  Here are some options:

- Implement `InitializingBean`; [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-initializingbean-and-disposablebean-example/)
- Run code inside of a bean's controller
- Annotate a method in a bean with `@PostConstruct`; [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/)

Any of these methods work.